# Better way to adding elements in data frame without looping in R

Tags: r, loops

I want to create a dataframe that calculates the odds ratio with the standard error and confidence intervals in R.

I have a dataset similar to the one like so:

```
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
f1 f2  f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 f10 f11 target
0   0    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
1   1    1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1
0   0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
1   0    0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0    0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1
1   1    1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0")
```

And create a function that calculates everything I need in the dataframe for a particular future in the data set like so:

```
get_ci <- function(df, feature) {
  tab <- table(df[[feature]], df$target)
  a <- tab[1,1]
  b <- tab[1,2]
  c <- tab[2,1]
  d <- tab[2,2]
  odds_ratio <- (a/b)/(c/d)
  standard_error <- sqrt(1/a + 1/b + 1/c + 1/d)
  log_ci_lower <- log(odds_ratio) - 1.96 + standard_error
  log_ci_upper <- log(odds_ratio) - 1.96 + standard_error
  ci_lower <- exp(log_ci_lower)
  ci_upper <- exp(log_ci_upper)

  df <- data.frame(Feature = feature,
                   `Odds Ratio` = odds_ratio,
                   `Standard Error` = standard_error,
                   `Lower Bound CI` = ci_lower,
                   `Upper Bound CI` = ci_upper
                   )

}
```

I want to create a DF that computes the odds ratio, standard error, and confidence interval for each features (f1-f11). What is the most efficient way to do this?
I am currently creating an empty dataframe and looping through the features in the df to populate one but I feel like this is not the right way to do it. I was looking at the apply functions, but not sure how I can apply that with my function I created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first `table` line in the function should be :

```
tab <- table(factor(df[[feature]], levels = 0:1), df$target)
```

otherwise, if you have all 1's and all 0's in a particular column the next lines would break.

With that change, you can use `lapply` passing the column names

```
result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(paste0('f', 1:11), get_ci, df = dat))
```

Or using `purrr`'s `map_df`

```
result <- map_df(paste0('f', 1:11), get_ci, df = dat)
```

Comment: Thanks. This was exactly something I was looking for. A solution through tidyverse.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution.

```
get_ci <- function(x, target) {
  tab <- table(factor(x, levels=0:1), target)  #changed
  ...
  ci_upper <- exp(log_ci_upper)

  c(`Odds Ratio` = odds_ratio,  # changed
    `Standard Error` = standard_error,
    `Lower Bound CI` = ci_lower,
    `Upper Bound CI` = ci_upper
  )
}

as.data.frame(apply(dat[,1:11], 2, function(x) { get_ci(x, dat$target) })) #changed
```